# How to add a click event to Axis labels in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a bar chart with the vertical axis this way

```
<mx:verticalAxis >
    <mx:CategoryAxis id="catAxis" title="Employee"  categoryField="id"/>
</mx:verticalAxis>
```

I would for the labels on the vertical axis to be clickable. So when a user clicks a label a click event fires and I can do something with it. I am not interested in clicking the bar itself (I know how to achieve that)

I tried adding an event listener to the CategoryAxis of type Mouse.Click but nothing gets fired.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it to work. I will post the answer so that others with a similar requirement can benefit. So, Timofei Davydik helped me look in the right direction. I have created an ActionScript class named `MyLabelRenderer` that extends `ChartLabel`. Inside its constructor, I added all my event listeners such as the mouse click event that I needed.

This was the tricky part. Thank you KB (a friend) for providing the correct instantiation. In the main application where my chart is I have to instantiate an instance of my new class `MyLabelRenderer` this way:

```
private var myLabelRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(MyLabelRenderer);
```

Then you can assign it to the AxisRenderer object this way:

```
<mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{catAxis}" labelRenderer="{myLabelRenderer}"/>
</mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
```

good luck...

Comment: Note: you should also be able to do this w/out creating a variable and using the curly brace binding expression, by specifying the `labelRenderer` using a String that is the fully qualified package name of your class. I typically do that w/`Lists` and it's `itemRenderer` property, which also expects a `ClassFactory`. I got to wondering why that worked... The docs for `ClassFactory` explain it as follows: "MXML lets you use the following syntax: `<mx:List id="myList" itemRenderer="ProductRenderer">`
The MXML compiler automatically creates the ClassFactory instance for you." How neat!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. Create your custom axis renderer (extend `AxisRenderer`) and assign it to the `verticalAxisRenderer` style property of `Axis` you're using.
2. Create your custom label renderer and assign it to `labelRenderer` property of your axis renderer. You can add click listeners inside it. *Note: label renderer must implement the IDataRenderer and IFlexDisplayObject interfaces.*

Comment: @Timofie Thank you for the suggestion, but I am not quite sure I understand your approach. Can you please provide some more details?